# Redirect character device output from terminal

Tags: linux, shell

An barcode scanner is connected via bluetooth and recognized by the system as /dev/hdiraw0. The scan result is appeared on shell. The goal is to get a result inside file. How can I redirect character device output?

Comment: What language are you using? Typically you would redirect stdout with the >symbol, i.e.  ./myapp > outputFile.  Of course you can pragmatically do this as well, but that implementation would be dependent on language

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code that is producing the output?

Comment: It is still no code. Just opened terminal. An each type I'm scanning a code, I got an output to the shell. And it's also seems like shell tries to execute this command.

Comment: In order for your application to dump out put to a terminal, it most be connected in some way. It sounds like you are either launching a program which launches a shell for monitoring, or you are starting the program via command line which causes all it's output to be displayed. In any case, I need more details about how the application is connected to the terminal to be able to help you.

Comment: _Something_ **must** be running to read from `/dev/hdiraw0` and write output to the terminal. It simply cannot be the case that you open a terminal/shell and output from the scanner starts appearing on it (or appear on all of them if you open multiple terminals and shells)

Comment: I understand. So how can make a system recognize it under a /dev/ttyUSB0. I had experience with another scanner type and it was mapped correctly.